# error: Unable to add source file : -p does not exist

Tags: java, ant, annotations, spoon

I am trying use spoon for process annotation. I followed the example (http://spoon.gforge.inria.fr/Doc/Basic#toc3) to run spoon with Ant (because spoon doesn't work with current version of Eclipse.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="TestBound" default="main" basedir=".">
    <!-- Sets variables which can later be used. -->
    <property name="src.dir" value="src" />
    <property name="build.dir" value="bin" />
    <property name="dist.dir" value="dist" />
    <property name="extlib.dir" value ="D:\Java_Lib\Libs" />


    <path id="build.classpath">
        <pathelement location="${extlib.dir}\spoon-core-1.5-jar-with-dependencies.jar" />
        <pathelement location="${extlib.dir}\SpoonTest.jar" />
    </path>
        <!-- define spoon task -->

    <taskdef name="spoon" classname="spoon.SpoonTask" classpathref= "build.classpath"/>


    <!-- Deletes the existing build, docs and dist directory-->
    <target name="clean" description="Deletes the existing build, docs and dist directory" >
        <delete dir="${build.dir}" />
        <delete dir="${dist.dir}" />
    </target>

    <!-- Creates the  build, docs and dist directory-->
    <target name="makedir" description="Creates the  build, docs and dist directory">
        <mkdir dir="${build.dir}" />
        <mkdir dir="${dist.dir}" />
    </target>

        <!-- Creates the  build, docs and dist directory-->
    <target name="modify" description="modify the source code" >

        <spoon classpathref="build.classpath" verbose="true">
            <sourceSet dir= "${src.dir}" includes= "*.java" />
            <processor type= "com.richardle.Bound2Processor" />
        </spoon>

    </target>

    <!-- Compile Java code -->
    <target name="compile" description="Compile Java code" depends="clean, makedir, modify">
        <javac destdir="${build.dir}" srcdir="${src.dir}" includeantruntime ="false">
            <classpath refid="build.classpath" />
        </javac>
    </target>

    <!-- 

    <target name="jar" description="Make jar file" depends="compile">
        <jar destfile="${dist.dir}\com.richardle.testgson.jar">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="com.richardle.testgson.TestGson"/>
            </manifest>
        </jar>
    </target>
    -->
    <target name="main" depends="compile">
        <description>Main target</description>
    </target>
</project>
```

Although, I put compiled jar file of processor and standalone spoon jar file in classpath, I still get the error when compiling with Ant

```
D:\SOFTWARE\Android\TestBound>ant
Buildfile: D:\SOFTWARE\Android\TestBound\build.xml

clean:
   [delete] Deleting directory D:\SOFTWARE\Android\TestBound\bin
   [delete] Deleting directory D:\SOFTWARE\Android\TestBound\dist

makedir:
    [mkdir] Created dir: D:\SOFTWARE\Android\TestBound\bin
    [mkdir] Created dir: D:\SOFTWARE\Android\TestBound\dist

modify:
    [spoon] Spoon version 2.0
    [spoon] error: Unable to add source file : -p does not exist
    [spoon] start processing...
    [spoon] spoon.support.JavaOutputProcessor
    [spoon] end of processing: 1 error
    [spoon] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.richardle.Bound2Processor;
    [spoon]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    [spoon]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    [spoon]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    [spoon]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    [spoon]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    [spoon]     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)

    [spoon]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    [spoon]     at spoon.AbstractLauncher.run(AbstractLauncher.java:581)
    [spoon]     at spoon.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:141)
    [spoon]     at spoon.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:52)
    [spoon] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ric
hardle.Bound2Processor;
    [spoon]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    [spoon]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    [spoon]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    [spoon]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    [spoon]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    [spoon]     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)

    [spoon]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    [spoon]     at spoon.AbstractLauncher.run(AbstractLauncher.java:581)
    [spoon]     at spoon.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:141)
    [spoon]     at spoon.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:52)

BUILD FAILED
D:\SOFTWARE\Android\TestBound\build.xml:34: Java returned: 1

Total time: 0 seconds

D:\SOFTWARE\Android\TestBound>
```

Is there any problem with my work? I have to use spoon (or some related processor), I can not use Java Annotation Processor because it can not modify the input source code, it just generate the new file.